# cadvisor and influxDB integration issue

Tags: docker, influxdb, cadvisor

I use influxDB to store the historical data produced by cadvisor and I encounter a problem. After the installation and connection of cadvisor and influxDB,the influxDB shows no data.Here are my docker configurations:

```
//for influxDB
docker run -d -p 8083:8083 -p 8086:8086 --expose 8090 --expose 8099 --name influxsrv tutum/influxdb
//for cadvisor
docker run --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
--volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
--volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
--volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \ 
--publish=8080:8080 \ 
--detach=true \
--link influxsrv:influxsrv \
--name=cadvisor \ 
google/cadvisor:latest \ 
-storage_driver_db=influxdb \
-storage_driver_host=influxsrv:8086
```

so when I planned to look the data in influxDB, I got the following message:

[image]

influxDB shows no data, can anyone tell me why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the cadvisor logs show? `docker logs cadvisor`

Comment: The used influxdb image is fairly outdated, the influxdb webinterface for example has been deprecated for a while now. Might want to try with a recent version.

Comment: when i use the command "docker logs cadvisor", I got the following message.     Registration of the rkt container factory failed: unable to communicate with Rkt api service: rkt: cannot tcp Dial rkt api service: dial tcp [::1]:15441: getsockopt: connection refused.      Sorry, this is my first time to use stackoverflow, I am not familar with it, i hope you can understand me, thanks.    @Robert

Comment: I found the telegraf also has a plugin that collect several kinds of metrics from docker containers. influxdb and telegraf belong to the same technology stack.I believe it will be more compatible.Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,the problem is solved. I try a little lower version of influxdb and cadvisor.